# Identifying this font

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Use fontspring's Matcherator and didn't get an exact font. I see this tyepface used a lot recently and was wondering if anyone knew what it was. Appreciate the help.

Source image is album artwork off of LCD Soundsystem's latest LP.

Comment: It looks like **bebas neue** but stretched.

Answer (score 6):

It is Heroic Condensed Regular

[image]

ADDENDUM: The comments need something. Here I have layered  MyFonts screenshot over the questioner's image. Part LCD is separated to own layer, the color is inverted and the blending mode is Exclusion. In the following image the texts are not aligned:

[image]

Non-fitting areas are orange or black. Fitting areas are light grey. In the following image the texts are aligned. Myfont screenshot is stretched only proportionally (=holding shift) so the glyphs have not been deformed. Every glyph has got the same scaling.

[image]

Questioner's version is 2 pixels larger everyhere when the spacing is the same. It can be caused by hinting, different rendering system or questioner's version has a stroke around the glyphs or the font is different. I do not believe in the last because the 2 pix difference is consistent. See a screenshot of the difference:

[image]

Comment: Where did you find that? I had a good look, and it simply led to me having to see this hideous cover more and more haha. If it's good design, then it's "over my head" :(

Comment: Assuming that you are asking how it was identified: I whitened the background and moved LCD to the same line as the rest of the text for easier visual comparison. Font Squirrel Matcherator gave numerous suggestions. Mostly they had wrong S and M. But when I added MyFonts to the searchables, the right was the first in the list. (sorry my previous explanation was from another case)

Comment: I don't think that the weight is correct. The strokes of the M and the Y terminate lower than your example.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I added something about it.